# GStreamer-Base-CRITICAL **: 10:55:45.909: basetransform: second attempt to fixate caps returned invalid (NULL) caps on pad vaapipostproc0:sink

Tags: matlab, video

I am using Ubuntu 22.04LTS and Matlab 2023b.

When I try to read some videos (with some of them, for some reason, there is no problem) with VideoReader the following warning appears:
(MATLAB:4591): GStreamer-Base-CRITICAL **: 10:55:45.909: basetransform: second attempt to fixate caps returned invalid (NULL) caps on pad vaapipostproc0:sink

It seams to be independent of video format as it happens with both avi and mp4 files.

I tried updating and reinstalling gstreamer and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the videos that i could not play had an audio coding of MPEG-4 AAC. I solved it by running the command:

```
sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```